# Chart not plotting data correctly (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts

I am having problems with a project which should show the acceleration of a simple pendulum swinging over time. It should model a negative cosine curve, and I have the X and Y axis set so that the cosine curve will peak at the top of the chart area. However, it does not do this. For example, the maximum acceleration is calculated to be 17.746 m/s^2, however on the chart it says the maximum is around 1.71 m/s^2. Screenshot attached below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AcmIDXsJIbzihH8Nq4mgSn1CofJCkQ6T/view?usp=sharing

I have wondered whether my maths are wrong or whether the problem lies somewhere in the chart. I have two other charts working, displacement and velocity of the pendulum, so I am confused as to why this will not work, especially as the coding behind each different chart is almost identical. I will attach all necessary code beneath.

```
Private Function CalculateAcceleration(ByVal amplitude As Double, ByVal frequency As Double, ByVal time As Double) As Double
        Dim acceleration, maxAcc As Double
        maxAcc = sq((2 * PI * frequency)) * amplitude
        acceleration = -(maxAcc * Cos(2 * PI * frequency * time))
        Return acceleration
    End Function
```

```
 Private Sub CreateAccelerationGraph(ByVal angularSpeed As Double, ByVal amplitude As Double, ByVal timePeriod As Double, ByVal frequency As Double)
        If AccelerationChart.Series("Acceleration").Points.Count <> 0 Then
            AccelerationChart.Series("Acceleration").Points.Clear()
        End If

        Dim maxAcceleration As Double = sq(angularSpeed) * amplitude

        With AccelerationChart.ChartAreas("Default")
            .AxisX.Minimum = 0
            .AxisX.Maximum = (1 * timePeriod)
            .AxisY.Minimum = -(maxAcceleration)
            .AxisY.Maximum = maxAcceleration
        End With

        Dim increment As Double = (1 * timePeriod) / 100

        For time As Double = 0 To (1 * timePeriod) Step increment

            Dim xPos, yPos As Double

            yPos = CalculateAcceleration(amplitude, frequency, time)
            xPos = time

            AccelerationChart.Series("Acceleration").Points.AddXY(xPos, yPos)

            Dim label As New CalloutAnnotation

            With label
                AccelerationChart.Annotations.Add(label)
            End With
        Next

    End Sub
```

```
 Private Sub SetUpAccelerationGraph()
        Dim innerPlotPosition As ElementPosition = New ElementPosition(10, 10, 80, 80)

        AccelerationChart.Series.Add("Acceleration")
        AccelerationChart.ChartAreas.Add("Default")

        With AccelerationChart.Series("Acceleration")
            .Color = Color.BlueViolet
            .BorderWidth() = 5
            .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline
        End With

        With AccelerationChart.ChartAreas("Default")
            .IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes = True
            .InnerPlotPosition = innerPlotPosition  ' sets the inner plot position
        End With
        AccelerationChart.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0.0}" 'sets the format of labels to 1dp
        AccelerationChart.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0.000}"

    End Sub
```

Comment: The maximum horizontal displacement, xMax, is (0.8 m)*sin(10 degrees) = 0.139 m. The frequency is 0.557 Hz. The maximum acceleration is -(2 pi f)^2 * xMax = -1.702 m/s^2. (- depending on which way up your y-axis is.)